# htaccess virtual directory rules

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure if it's possible or not, but this is what I'm trying to achieve:

I'm writing a simple php script that will have different url's based on section.
For example:

```
http://domain.com/section1/
http://domain.com/section2/
http://domain.com/section3/
```

Main file for accessing each section is called http://mydomain.com/section.php

Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule section/([^/]*)/$ section.php?section=$1 [L]
```

The rule above does not work. Do I need to create new rule for each section, or not. Like:

```
RewriteRule section1/([^/]*)/$ section.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule section2/([^/]*)/$ section.php?section=$1 [L]
RewriteRule section3/([^/]*)/$ section.php?section=$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a numeric char before the slash. Therefore, the rule should be

```
RewriteRule section(\d+)/(.*)$ section.php?section=$1 [L]
```

Please not that this would not do anything with the query string that is passed after the slash. However, it's in $2 if you need it.

Edit: if your section pattern isn't numeric, then try:

```
RewriteRule (page|search|blog)/(.*)$ section.php?section=$1 [L]
```

that will pass the string `page`, `search` or `blog` as section parameter

Comment: section names are just for demo purposes. The actual names are RewriteRule page, RewriteRule search, RewriteRule blog